# Create employee-manager relationship in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, activedirectorymembership, active-directory-group

So got to put some data structure for employee-manager relationship in Active diractory.

The employee list already exists in Active directory. Can I create Manager group and assign some employee as Manager. After that can I assign some other employee to those managers.

Please help. TIA
Ron

Comment: You *are* aware that each user in Active Directory [has a `Manager` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676859%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for just that purpose, right?

Comment: Thanks Marc. Not actually, will get to see these today sometime in current structure. So I can add the attribute Manager to employee and first part is done. Is there a way to associate employee/employees to manager/managers?

Comment: The employees will all already have a `Manager` attribute - just populate those with the DN (distinguished name) of their managers - and you should be set. Of course - those managers also have a `Manager` attribute, so you can create any depth of managerial hierarchy as you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each object of type `Person` in Active Directory already has a `Manager` attribute.

By setting the manager's DN (distinguished name) into that attribute, you're effectively assigning a user to his/her manager.

```
DirectoryEntry deEmployee = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=John Employee,OU=Sales,DC=Corp,DC=com");

deEmployee.Property["manager"] = "CN=Peter Manager,OU=Sales,DC=Corp,DC=com";
deEmployee.CommitChanges();
```

The employees will all already have a `Manager` attribute - just populate those with the DN (distinguished name) of their managers - and you should be set.

Of course - those managers also have a `Manager` attribute, so you can create any depth of managerial hierarchy as you wish